# PhantomJS scraping through a proxy with a php wrapper

Tags: php, web-scraping, phantomjs

Has anyone had success with scraping using php-phantomjs through a proxy server?

ie, something like get_website_contents() :

```
<?php

$scrape_this_url = 'http://www.coolsite.com';

$proxy_url = 'www.myproxy.com';
$proxy_port = '8080';
$proxy_username = 'myusername';
$proxy_password = 'mypassword';

$website_contents = get_website_contents( $scrape_this_url, $proxy_url, $proxy_port, $proxy_username, $proxy_password );

echo $website_contents;

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the error you are seeing? Please edit your question accordingly. Is your question whether it is at all possible to use php-phantomjs with a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation where you can find the `addOption` method:
http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/advanced.html

I think that you can use `$client->addOption("--proxy=address:port")` e.g.  `$client->addOption("--proxy=12.34.56.78:80")`.

More otions: http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html